# Docker compose mirroring folder

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to create a mongodb service that runs in a docker container. My purpose is persist all the data inside container in the host machine. For this I have a `docker-compose.yml` file, whose content is:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: myrootmongousername
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootmongopassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dbnameiwanttocreate
    ports:
      - '27010:27017'
    volumes:
      - 'mongodata:/data'
```

As you can see, my `volumes` section declares to drop all content of `/data` folder inside container into `mongodata` folder in host. I created a folder named `mongodata` just at the same height that my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
myprojectfolder
|__docker-compose.yml
|__mongodata
```

When I do `docker-compose up` it creates a container and I can connect and so on. However, my `mongodata` folder is completely empty. That's cannot be true, because if I go inside docker container (`docker exec -it <container-id> bash`) and explore `/data` folder, it is not empty at all.

What is my mistake here?

Thanks!

Comment: You need use absolute path for the host folder `/users/xxxx/mongodata:/data` instead of `mongodata:/data`. In your current config, you're using docker managed named volume. See the [docker-compose volume document](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)

Comment: ...or a relative path `./mongodata`.

Comment: Thanks Dai, David Maze. I just tried both. Not working, still empty folder.

Comment: @Carlos have you got to a solution? I have the same issue and couldn't solve it. I'd appreciate if you could share the solution with us. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following Docker compose file works for the directory structure below on ubuntu 18.04, check if docker has permissions to write into the local folder `mongodata`

If that doesn't work paste logs by running `docker-compose logs` will update answer specific to the issue.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: myrootmongousername
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrootmongopassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: dbnameiwanttocreate
    ports:
      - '27010:27017'
    volumes:
      - './mongodata:/data'
```

```
├── docker-compose.yml
└── mongodata
    ├── configdb
    └── db
```